# DocuSign / Ruby - unsupported_grant_type when trying to obtain token

Tags: ruby, jwt, docusignapi

We are moving away from using the DocuSign::Esign gem and we are trying to make the API calls following the [How to get an access token with JWT Grant authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/#create) instructions. The consent has already been granted for this application when we set up this originally with the DocuSign::Esign gem.

I am getting the following error:

> {"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"unsupported_grant_type"}

I am using Ruby and am running this code in the console

```
config = Padrino.config.docusign
current_time = Time.now.utc

header = { 
  typ: 'JWT', 
  alg: 'RS256'
}

body = {
  iss: config.integrator_key,
  sub: config.user_id,
  iat: current_time.to_i,
  exp: (current_time + 1.hour).to_i,
  aud: config.host,
  scope: 'signature impersonation'
}

key_file = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAiOMDM5jdGYTEOC/nFVUTQ3+5U2TCUpEKyUD+mByldDbgvT9q
. . .
jDjfX6L15x8JcY9eiXvCvZNF6Za2dg8cagK+ff5d6KLodmVFD5o=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key_file)

token = JWT.encode(body, private_key, 'RS256')

uri = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token'
data = {
  grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
  assertion: token 
}
auth_headers = {content_type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

However, when I call the api, I get a RestClient::Bad response error

```
irb(main):352:0> begin
irb(main):353:1>   RestClient.post(uri, data.to_json, auth_headers)
irb(main):354:1> rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
irb(main):355:1>   JSON.parse(e.http_body)
irb(main):356:1> end
=> {"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The JWT decodes correctly when I check it in https://jwt.io/. I am using the grant_type exactly as provided in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm,

1. `scope` claim only needs to be `signature` (`impersonation` is implied since you're using the JWT grant flow.)
2. For the `aud` claim, what is `config.host`? It should be `account-d.docusign.com` for the developer system (Do **not** include `https://`)
3. Your main error is that you are sending the data hash in JSON format. That's wrong, it must be sent in url form format. Try

```
RestClient.post(uri, data, auth_headers)
```

instead. (Don't convert the data to json.)

Comment: Well now it works just fine. Thank you for that tip, removing the `.to_json` was the ticket.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help and thank you for the check!